# Adding list to a list in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, numpy

I have code that generates a list (`target = [  ]`) by appending strings (`token`) to it.

Now I have another list say `A = [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']]` that I would like to add to the `target` list, without touching the original list. Just add on to the original, may I know how to do it? thanks

```
    def read_samples_by_string(self, path):
        for tokens in self.read_tokens(path):

            target =  []
            print(type(target))  # this is <type 'list'>
            
            for token in tokens:
                
                target.append(token)
                print(type(token))   # this is <type 'str'>               
            yield target
            print(target)

Input list : 
A = [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']]

output :
['O','X', 'Y', 'Z']
['L', 'M'] 
['J', 'K', 'W'] 

Expected output
['O','X', 'Y', 'Z']
['L', 'M'] 
['J', 'K', 'W'] 
['A', 'B']
['C', 'D']
```

Comment: How you are exporting the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final_list = []
list1 = [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']]
list2 = [['O','X', 'Y', 'Z'],['L', 'M'],['J', 'K', 'W']]

for l2 in list2:
    final_list.append(l2)

for l1 in list1:
    final_list.append(l1)

for l in final_list:
    print(l)
```